# Не получается 301 редирект

Tags: apache, html, javascript, php

Всем доброго времени суток, подскажите как в .htaccess сделать так, чтобы вместо [site.ru/page1.html](http://site.ru/page1.html) отображалось [site.ru/page1.](http://site.ru/page1.) Смотрел как это сделать в мане 301 редиректа, но так и не заработало у меня...

```
  Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite www.site.ru -> site.ru -- used with SEO Strict URLs plugin
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^site\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
#redirect index.php on / 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://site.ru/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/page1.html$ http://site.ru/page1 [R=301,nc]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вар. 1**

```
Redirect 301 /page1.html http://site.ru/page1/
```

**Вар. 2**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page1.html$ http://site.ru/page1 [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Ни первый, ни второй вариант не сработал...да я и делал собственно говоря так, поэтому и задал здесь вопрос. И вот еще вопрос если у меня несколько страниц, то мне для каждой получается писать редирект подобный? может есть какой-нибудь универсальный метод, чтобы разрешение документа не выводилось? В шапку приложил содержимое моего файла .htaccess может в нем где проблема?

Comment: Для 1-го варианта нужен mod_alias — проверьте.

Для 2-го исправил слегка строку - не нужен был слэш в начале.